# How to print only those numbers of a column which are greater than certain number in bash

Tags: csv, awk

I want to print only those numbers of a column which is greater than certain number provided by the user.
My file is like this:

```
Name,roll_no,marks
Honey,1,40
Joe,2,34
Viky,3,56
```

I tried:

```
read -p 'enter a number= ' $num
cat class.csv | awk 'FS=",";if($3>$num){print$3}else{print "no matches"}'
```

if i enter `35` then output should be

```
40
56
```

And if i enter `100` then output should be

```
no matches
```

But this is giving me wrong output. Plz help me :(

Comment: Try this.
`awk 'FS="," -v num=$num {if($3 > num) print $3; else print "no matches" }'`

Comment: This is not working either syntax error occurs.

Comment: My bad. Should be: `awk -F="," -v num=$num '{if ($3 > num) print $3; else print "no matches" }'